# Comprobar real autenticación con jwt en javascript

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, autenticación, local-storage

quiero implementar **autenticación jwt** a un administrador hecho en **vuejs2**, con **api rest** en **laravel**.

leí muchos tutoriales y básicamente todos guardan el token devuelto en localhost, en vuex o en una cookie. y sólo checkean si el usuario está logeado consultando esa variable:

```
// check en vuex
if (this.$store.state.auth == true)
```

o

```
// check en localstorage
if (localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

mi duda es que, al fin de cuentas éstas variables pueden ser modificados fácilmente en el frontend con, por poner un ejemplo, el *web developer tools*. cambias el `state.auth` a `true`, o cargas cualquier valor al token del localstorage y se tiene acceso al administrador como si realmente estuvieras autenticado.

sé que de igual modo no podrá modificar nada en la base de datos sin un `token` válido, pero igual puede ingresar y es lo que me gustaría evitar.

¿estoy entendiendo o haciendo algo mal? ¿es posible evitar ésto? ¿existe alguna alternativa para evitar ésto?

¡muchas gracias!

Comment: quieres decodificar el jwt en tu front?si es eso , lo puedes hacer el problema es el token de validacion estara en el front y esto te traera n vulnerabilidades

Comment: hola @JackNavaRow no, quiero evitar que cualquier usuario que modifique **manualmente** el `auth` a `true`, o que cargue cualquier valor al `token` del `localstorage` pueda ingresar al administrador. ya que, según los tutoriales que leí, es así como verifican si está autenticado el usuario.

Comment: en conclusion, quieres codificar tus valores y luego decodificarlo?, en realidad cuando consumes  un servicio a excepcion del login en el header va el token de validacion tu back se encargara de validarlo de no ser correcto no te dejara consumir el servicio

Comment: **no quiero codificar ni decodificar nada**. como intenté explicar arriba, mi problema es con la modificación **MANUAL** (desde el web developer tools por ejemplo) de esas variables, y que gracias a eso alguien pueda ingresar al admin sin autorización. ya que por código javascript yo checkeo si auth es igual a true.

Comment: tu titulo es distinto a la pregunta original , de igual forma la unica forma que tienes para asegurar esto es preguntarle a tu servidor la accion a realizar, para eso te coloca por seguridad en el header la accion, queda de tu parte validar el token que sea correcto y tenga permisos, una vez realizado esto hacer un redirect; asi protegras tu aplicacion

Comment: Por si aún no esta claro, lo que @JackNavaRow intenta decir es, no debería ser un problema que el usuario manipule el `token` (_agregue o modifique_) ya que el `backend` siempre debe recibir el `token`, validarlo y si no es válida, no permitir al usuario realizar la acción y/o redirigirlo a otro lado.

Comment: claro, entiendo perfecto que sin un `token válido` no va a poder hacer ninguna modificación, pero a lo que voy es que de igual modo podrá entrar al admin. ¿ustedes creen que es una buena práctica hacer una llamada al api validando el `token` por **cada vez** que el usuario cambie de ruta? tengo la sospecha de que es una demanda excesiva de consultas al backend. me gustaría saber su opinión sobre esta posible solución.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que te preocupa que alguien ingrese a una ruta "protegida" del frontend de tu aplicación modificando las variables mediante las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador. Puedes revisar "Navigations Guards" que ofrece el router de vuejs, para "interceptar" esos cambios de rutas en el frontend.

https://elabismodenull.wordpress.com/2017/05/22/vuejs-interceptores-de-navegacion-entre-rutas/

Algo que tambien podrias tener en cuenta es que tu codigo debe ir minificado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, para que sea aceptada agrega un ejemplo como implementar el Navigations Guards

Comment: exacto @turkey! eso mismo empecé a investigar éstos días: `navigations guards` en **vuejs**. ahora la pregunta que me surge es: ¿es una buena práctica verificar que el token sea válido cada vez que el usuario quiera acceder a cualquier ruta? un api call cada vez que va navegando entre las rutas me suena un poco pesado para una aplicación. me gustaría saber sus opiniones.

Comment: Vale Raúl disculpa hace mucho no usaba stack. Gracias

Comment: En realidad no te conviene verificar el token, la razón es por que tendrías que tener el string que utilizas para generar el token, entonces tendrías una invulnerabilidad grande, lo que yo hago es verificar en el servidor que el token sea valido cada vez que hago una consulta a la API, los guardias de navegación solo verifican que haya una valor, no verifican el token o algo así, pero es simple sino el token no es valido no podrán navegar